# Completeness of space of $k$-times differentiable functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I'm having trouble solving exercise 7.5 from Otto Forsters Analysis 2 book:

Let $\displaystyle U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset and $C^k_b(U)$ the set of all $k$-times continuously differentiable functions $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ with bounded differentials $D^\alpha f \; \forall\; \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ with $\vert \alpha \vert = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i = k $.

And $\vert\vert \cdot \vert\vert_{k} : C^k_b(U) \to \mathbb{R} $

with

$\vert\vert f \vert\vert_{k} := \sum_{\vert \alpha \vert = k} 
\frac{1}{\alpha!} \sup\{ \vert D^\alpha f(x) \vert, x \in U\} $.

Note that $\alpha! := \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i!$ and
and $D^\alpha f := 
\frac{\partial^{\vert\alpha \vert}f}
{
\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots 
\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}
}$

a) I have shown that $\vert\vert \cdot \vert\vert_{k} : C^k_b(U) \to \mathbb{R} $ is a norm

b) Show for $f, g, \in C^k_b(U)$: $\vert\vert fg \vert\vert_{k} \leq
\vert\vert f \vert\vert_{k} \vert\vert g \vert\vert_{k}$

c) Show that $( C^k_b(U), \vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_{k})$ is complete.

I'd be happy about any hints to solutions for b) and c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in the book you find the product rule:

$$D^\alpha(fg)=\sum_{\beta\le\alpha}\frac{\alpha!}{\beta!(\alpha-\beta)!}D^\beta fD^{\alpha-\beta}g.$$

Let's write $\sup|\phi|=||\phi||_0$. It's clear that $||\phi\psi||_0\le||\phi||_0||\psi||_0$, hence

$$||D^\alpha(fg)||_0\le\sum_{\beta\le\alpha}\frac{\alpha!}{\beta!(\alpha-\beta)!}||D^\beta f||_0||D^{\alpha-\beta}g||_0.$$Insert that inequality into the definition of $||fg||_k$. Also write out the product $||f||_k||g||_k$. Something magic happens, and you get (b).

For (c), say $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $C^k$. Then $(D^\alpha f_n)$ is *uniformly* Cauchy for all $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\le k$. So for all such $\alpha$ there exists $g_\alpha$ so that $D^\alpha f_n\to g_\alpha$ uniformly. Let $f=g_0$. Now some theorem from advanced calculus shows that $g_\alpha=D^\alpha f$ and you're done... (why?)

Comment: How dou you define ${\beta\le\alpha}$ for $\beta, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$?

Comment: By (standard in this context) definition $\alpha\le\beta$ if $\alpha_j\le\beta_j$ for all $j$.

Comment: I don't get the magic required for b)... Concerning c): What you say suffices, because of the uniform convergence, which preserves the continutity and boundedness of the converging partial derivatives. It would of course be nice to know the theorem stating that the limit of the partial deriviatives of a converging function sequence equals the partial derivative of the limiting function.

Comment: Well, show us what you got for $||fg||_k\le???$ and what you get when you multiply out $||f||_k||g||_k$.

Comment: $\vert \vert fg \vert \vert_{k} \leq \sum_{\vert \alpha \vert \leq k} \sum_{\vert \beta \vert \leq \alpha} \frac{1}{\alpha! (\alpha - \beta)!} \vert \vert D^\beta f \vert \vert_0 \vert \vert D^{\alpha - \beta} g \vert \vert_0 $ and $\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{k} \vert \vert  g \vert \vert_{k} = \sum_{\vert \alpha \vert \leq k} \sum_{\vert \beta \vert \leq k} \frac{1}{\alpha! \beta!} \vert \vert D^\alpha f \vert \vert_0  \vert \vert D^\beta g \vert \vert_0 $

Comment: That's right for my first question, except it's $\beta\le\alpha$, not $|\beta|\le\alpha$ and you got the brackets bollixed on the \frac. Now what about $||f||_k||g||_k$? (Probably things will be clearer if you use letters other than $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the second...)

Comment: Right, except for obvious typos. Change the letters on the second to avoid confusion. Every term in the first sum also appears in the second!

Comment: So the second sum is $\sum_{\vert \beta \vert \leq k} 
\sum_{\vert \alpha \vert \leq k} 
\frac{1}{\alpha! \beta!} \vert \vert D^\beta f \vert \vert_0  \vert \vert D^\alpha g \vert \vert_0 = 
 \sum_{\vert \beta \vert \leq k} 
\sum_{\vert \delta:= \alpha + \beta \vert \leq k + \vert \beta \vert} 
\frac{1}{(\delta - \beta)! \beta!} \vert \vert D^{\beta} f \vert \vert_0  \vert \vert D^{\delta - \beta} g \vert \vert_0 $

Comment: And the terms for the first sum are included because $ \{\vert \alpha \vert \leq k \} \times \{ \beta \leq \alpha \} \subset \{ \vert \beta \vert \leq k \} \times \{ \vert \delta \vert \leq \ k + \vert \beta \vert \} $? I'm really confused by the indices...

Comment: I told you, twice, to use letters other than $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the second sum

Comment: Say it's $\gamma$ and $\delta$ in the second sum. Given a term in the first sum, you can find it in the second sum at $\gamma = \alpha$, $\delta = \alpha-\beta$.

Comment: Or rather $\gamma = \beta$, $\delta=\alpha-\beta$.